# How do I get class='active' working properly?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get my nav-tabs styled and working properly. I believe I am not setting up the `class="active"` the correct way. It sets my first TAB/PAGE active by default, but when I click on either one of my other TABS/PAGES it still Highlights(background-color active) on my first TAB/Page.
How do I configure it to Highlight the active/clicked-on Tab?

This is what I have right now for my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Active Projects", projects_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Delinquent Projects", delinquent_projects_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Completed/Closed Projects", closed_projects_path %></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: on click on a tab will refresh the page or just show content with in that tab

Comment: `$('li').removeClass` then `$(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: where's your JavaScript that resets the active class when you click on another tab?

Comment: @andi excellent question. And this is why I am here. A good example of the .js code needed would be appreciated.

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with the question; it is about rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so you need to create a helper like

```
def active_link_to(text, link)
    content_tag(:li, :class => request.fullpath == link ? 'active' : nil) do
        link_to text, link
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When rendering the navbar, you should check current path. If it's, say, "/users", then you highlight "Users" menu item and not others. If it's "/orders", you highlight "Orders". And so on.

Here's a little gem to do this work for you: [active_link_to](https://github.com/twg/active_link_to).

```
active_link_to 'Users', '/users'
# => <a href="/users" class="active">Users</a>
```

Comment: Splendid- I've never heard about this gem!

Comment: I will check out this gem now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is checking the controller param since every action would have the same active tab.

`<li class=<%= params[:controller] == "users" ? "active": "" >`

(I may have syntax errors since I'm getting rusty, specially with the quotes).

Every other solution listed here should work too.

GL & HF!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/twg/active_link_to

`gem 'active_link_to'`

Then simplify your code to:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <%= active_link_to "Active Projects", projects_path, :wrap_tag => :li %>
    <%= active_link_to "Delinquent Projects", delinquent_projects_path, :wrap_tag => :li %>
    <%= active_link_to "Completed/Closed Projects", closed_projects_path, :wrap_tag => :li %>
</ul>
```

Edit: Didn't notice answer above. At least here's an example :)